# SSRS: Table on new page if it passes a page break

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-2016

I have an SSRS report with multiple subreports, around 12. All subreports contain tables. Whenever a table starts at the bottom of a page, it will continue at the next page, splitting the table in half.

How do I put the entire table on the next page if these cases happen? Is there any way?

Comment: `Tablix` and `Subreport` have `KeepTogether` property but I never understand exactly its rules. You can give a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-report-items-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

if you put the table in a rectangle, there's a setting on the rectangle that says "keep on one page if possible." you could also just repeat the headers on the next page, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-row-and-column-headers-on-multiple-pages-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017